# Creating a large amount of convex polygons using existing coordinates

Tags: polygon-creation, arcgis-pro, convex-hull

I downloaded the georeferenced event dataset (top left) from this website: http://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/ It consists of coordinates of violent conflicts which differ in time and space. My aim is to connect the coordinates of one country during the same time (say a month) in a way that it forms a convex area. In other words, I want to create a polygon by connection only the outer coordinates with each other. I want to do this for every country for each time period; therefore, only an automatised process will do.

If you would like to see a picture, you can have a look at the code book of the top right(!) dataset. In case you wonder why I don't simply download the top right dataset: The data is only available until 2010, but I need it until 2014.

I work with the trial version of ArcGIS Pro 1.3

I have worked with ArcGIS before, but this is a few years ago and I used it for quite basic procedures.

Comment: I'd be using R or Python for this, no need to put a UI in the way. It's a pretty straightforward workflow for geospatial programming

Comment: Thanks, I can try with Stata or ask if someone here knows how to do it with R or Python.

Answer (score 3):

Input:

[image]

Workflow:

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management("crime_points","C:/FELIX_DATA/SCRARCH/SCRATCH.gdb/crime_points_Dissolve","CID","#","MULTI_PART","DISSOLVE_LINES")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("crime_points_Dissolve","C:/FELIX_DATA/SCRARCH/SCRATCH.gdb/Buffers","0.5 Meters","FULL","ROUND","NONE","#")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Buffers","Shape","!Shape!.convexHull()","PYTHON_9.3","#")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the code! This looks exactly like what I need to do. I will try this out as soon as I have time. Take care!

Comment: Ok, I tried it out. I replicated the commands underlying the first two lines of code without problems, but when I use Calculate Field, I receive this error message:"ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Unable to update area or length field in response to shape update
Failed to execute (CalculateField)."
Any idea what went wrong there?

Comment: Try with Shape file and editing mode

Comment: Also use union of inputs in environment settings extent

Comment: It seems you are jumping over time meridian. All shapes but points having issues with it. Try with country sitting in single hemisphere.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by @FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/207123/115) should work using any license level but if you have an Advanced level license then ArcGIS Pro can create your convex hulls using the CONVEX_HULL option of its [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing polygons which represent a
>   specified minimum bounding geometry enclosing each input feature or
>   each group of input features.

You would use its group_option of LIST and the field(s) you want to group the points by.