# Create polygons convex hull with arc basic

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, basic-license-level, convex-hull

I have a bunch of polygons to make from points that need to be more precise than the min bounding box of closest rectangle or circle but don't have an advanced license. Does anybody have a workaround for this? I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: Run !Shape!.convexHull() on shape field in field calculator. Parser is Python

Comment: Thanks Felix but I'm not sure where to go from here. I ran !Shape!.convexHull() on the point file in the "Shape" field. Is there another step?

Comment: My fault, I thought you've got polygons already. This http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207115/creating-a-large-amount-of-convex-polygons-using-existing-coordinates/207123#207123 should help providing you have attributes in points to dissolve them by

Comment: @FelixIP, a very smart solution, indeed. Can this question be marked as duplicate then?

Comment: @fatih_dur Yes it is. It is a duplicate of the one older